Change ItemNotFoundUrl Setting in sitecore
I must display my custom page content if the media library item(ex: pdf files) is not in Sitecore. I am able do it by changing the value of these two settings in sitecore.config
 <setting name="ItemNotFoundUrl" value="/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx"/>
 <setting name="LinkItemNotFoundUrl" value="/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx"/>

But the URL is also getting changed, Is there any way to keep the URL as it is and display the content of my custom page?

@sanjak kumar is your solution using SXA?

Yes, It is SXA Site

Uploaded the answer below to change the below settings to transfer the request to 404 page rather than redirecting..Let me know in case you have any doubts.

While using SXA, there is a handler for transferring the request when media item is not found.
Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.MediaRequestHandler.HandleErrors, Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandlin

This handler enables to transfer the request to 404 page when the media item is not found, thus the url remains same and content of 404 page is displayed. In order to enable this functionality, below steps need to be performed.

Set RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect setting as true through following configuration patch.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
      <settings>
            <setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect"">
                <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
            </setting>
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>


Set the 404 page inside Site Settings item in the Page not found link field as below.


Using above changes, whenever the media item is not found, it will keep the url as it is and display the content of 404 page set above inside Site Settings item.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any doubts.
